diff drive robot cannot turn gazebo using bullet featherstone physics engine
I'm working on mobile manipulator with a differential drive on Gazebo (on ros jazzy). I'm using bullet featherstone physics engine because it works with mimic joint. I noticed that the robot can move forward and backward without issues but struggles to rotate in place. Instead of rotating, the robot slips, with no significant rotation.
The default physics engine (ode) works fine, the problem exists when using the bullet featherstone physics engine. I first assume there was a problem with collision parameters itself but I notice that even with the sample sdf, with 0 friction caster, the robot seem to struggle rotating in place.
Is there a specific parameters to enable the diff drive robot to rotate in place? Or is this the limitation of the physics engine?
Steps to reproduce:

bringup sample diff drive sdf using bullet featherstone engine

ros2 launch ros_gz_sim gz_sim.launch.py gz_args:='diff_drive.sdf -r -v4 --physics-engine gz-physics-bullet-featherstone-plugin'


send topic

gz topic -t /model/vehicle_green/cmd_vel -m gz.msgs.Twist -p "linear: {x: 0.0}, angular: {z: 5.0}"


https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-physics/issues/697#issuecomment-2445495247
It seems that the default torsional friction value in bullet is causing the problem as stated in the github issue. For now, the workaround is setting the torsional friction to 0 for both the wheel and the ground plane.
